# Hibernate - adding two class in one table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

How i can add based and descendant class in one table with Hibernate?

Based class

```
 public class Id{

 protected int id
 }
```

Descendant class

```
 public classs User exetends Id{
 public String username;
 public String password;
 }
```

In one table USERS with properties: id, username, password.

Comment: did you try google, check this link http://www.javatpoint.com/hibernate-table-per-hierarchy-using-annotation-tutorial-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i understood.

You want to have a `Base` entity. And that `Base` entity should be extended by other `Descendant` entities. In other words the `Descendant` should be having all the properties from the Base entity. One use case for this design is to have common properties(id, createdDate, updatedDate) for all `Descendant` class in a `Base` entity class.

One way to go with this is:

> BaseEntity(Base Class)

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    //..setter and getters
}
```

> User(Descendant Class)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name; //User specific properties

    //..setters and getters here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to mark them with `@Entity` to show that they are tables, then in the top level set the table name with `@Table`. To use inheritance, you need to select a strategy: for this instance you want SINGLE_TABLE. Then in order to select the correct type a `@DiscriminatorColumn` is required, setting the column name and the type of discriminator - in this case I have chosen *INTEGER*. You'll need to also add to the type annotation updatable = false and insertable = false so they cannot be modified.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_NAME")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE",discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
public class Id {

    @Column(name="TYPE", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Integer type;

}
```

On your sub classes you need to mark them with `@Entity` and a `@DiscriminatorValue` (in this case 1).

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "1")
public classs User exetends Id{

    public String username;
    public String password;

}
```